# Update div or another html tag

Tags: jquery, ajax

I wanna update div tag after ajax:

```
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET', // or POST, no difference
            url: "<?php echo Yii::app()->createUrl('words/nextWord');?>",
            success: function(data) {
                // There need add code
            }
        })
    }
```

After ajax i have response whole page with change change and me need change word in this tags or substitute div.
I tried use:

```
$('#word').load("<?php echo Yii::app()->createUrl('words/nextWord'); ?> #word");
```

Before code above i had

```
<span id="word" class="word">dog</span>
```

After code above i had

```
<span id="word" class="word">
    <span id="word" class="word"> good</span>
</span>
```

Comment: what console.log(data) gives?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly what you are trying to do but the `.html()` function will replace the contents of the `#word` element.

```
$('#word').html("<?php echo Yii::app()->createUrl('words/nextWord'); ?>");
```

Comment: Lol, no. Its url like 'archive.php'.

Comment: Your post mentioned you wanted to update the #word element... What is it you are trying to do.  Possibly re-word your question

Answer (score 0):

Content from this url **words/nextWord** is probably the

```
"<span id="word" class="word"> good</span>"
```

but it should return only " good". So load method insert that content in it self. Try to call that url directly in your browser and check what content it returns.